# Windows Start Screen doesn't show background picture

Tags: windows-10

[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpoep.jpg)

So the question is - I use DisplayFusion to regulate my double monitor wallpaper. But after I changed it, I clicked Start (Windows button) and I saw just black background under my icons. Do you where can I regulate this? Because in options I found only the ability to put a picture on the Lock Screen. You can look at the attached screenshot to understand the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows 10 version? Any black theme enabled?

Comment: How did you define the background image? What happens if you do it again?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the option Show my Desktop Background on Start Screen is enabled. 
https://www.eightforums.com/threads/start-screen-show-desktop-background-on-in-windows-8-1.28202/

The following link is about How To Span Wallpaper Images Across Groups of Monitors:
https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/how-to-span-wallpaper-images-across-groups-of-monitors/?ID=ebf54915-9740-4296-a97d-41ec7784b84f

Best Regards